# GIMP: How to extend .xcf file dimensions

Tags: gimp

I have a .xcf file created in GIMP of 320x480 pixels size. Now I want to extend it to 320x640 pixels with all the layers intact.

I have an option of creating new file and copy each layer one by one. But thats too tiresome. It has around 50 layers.

P.S.: I'm using GIMP 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Image/Canvas Size** option from the menu in order to change the size of the image without changing the layer's sizes. There is an option to choose which layers you wish to resize in order to adjust them to the size of the new canvas, center the layers, etc.

[image]

This may be helpful for you, I am using GIMP 2.8 but it works on 2.6 the same.

Good luck!

Comment: voila... worked like charm!! And I was thinking on copying each layer. Thanks @Geppettvs , you saved me a lot of time. (I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, I'll accept your answer after 6 minutes) Thanks again.